# Recommended Magento Nginx configuration failing

Tags: nginx

Pulled the recommended Nginx configuration from http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento.

I modified it slightly for my website: staging.website.com, no www or anything like that.

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
## SSL directives might go here
    server_name staging.website.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}
```

The problem I keep running into is a 403: Forbidden message in the web browser and this log in /var/log/nginx/error.log:

```
[error] 7702#0: *5 "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 12.34.56.78, server: staging.website.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "
```

I've reset the permissions of my webroot several times and there should be no reason why I can't access it. I can only assume that it has something to do with my site configuration file.

Comment: If this question was to be placed in any other Q&A site, shouldn't it have been Server Fault?